# boost crash when deleting condition_variable after fork

Tags: c++, linux, boost-asio

I have a shared library that I load with my app.
When the library is being loaded it creates an instance of boost::condition_variable.
and deletes it when it exists (using at_exit()).

My app calls fork(). and it seems that when the child process ends, the library tries to delete the condition_variable, and fails on the assert.

I think that it is related to the fork, because the only the child process (which terminates only after the parent process ends) causing the crash.

Does anyone have any idea why it happens?
Does anyone have any idea how to solve it (without try/catch)?

The crash:

```
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install boost-filesystem-1.41.0-11.el6_1.2.x86_64 boost-system-1.41.0-11.el6_1.2.x86_64 glibc-2.12-1.47.el6.x86_64 libgcc-4.4.6-3.el6.x86_64 libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.x86_64
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000003eca232885 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x0000003eca234065 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x0000003eca22b9fe in __assert_fail_base () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x0000003eca22bac0 in __assert_fail () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#4  0x00007f64bab101f6 in ?? () at /usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/condition_variable_fwd.hpp:86
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be happening because you fork() but do not exec(), which leaves you with two processes each having the atexit handler registered.  To overcome this, consider simply adding a global bool (which will be one per process) which will be checked by the atexit handler before taking any action.  Then, simply set that bool in your child process so its handler does nothing.

For more on this, see: [Can I undo or remove an atexit command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310673/can-i-undo-or-remove-an-atexit-command)